# dataTable: passing extra data to php server-side script

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatables

I need to change the "where-clause" in the sql statement that is used to fetch data from a db and display it in dataTables by changing the value of myInput and passing it on to the server-side. I have this code:

```
<input id=myInput value="london">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#example').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "server_processing.php",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.myInput = $('#myInput').val();
        }
    }
    });
} );
</script>
```

Server-side has this code:

```
<?php
//...HERE I have defined these: $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns 

$where="`office`='$_POST['myInput']'";

require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo    json_encode(SSP::simple($_GET,$sql_details,$table,$primaryKey,$columns,$where));
```

Where am I going wrong?  I have tried this based on many examples and post on the internet but I am ending up with the same result.

Comment: What is this result? What is your desired result?

Comment: My desired result is that myInput value gets posted to server side script.  Currently it brings an error on the line:

Comment: $where="`office`='$_POST['myInput']'";

Comment: Sounds like it does not know $_POST['myInput']

Comment: Which error? Please copy the complete error message into your question.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your PHP script.

1. You're using quoted keys in `$_POST['myInput']` without curly braces
   syntax.
2. You're not escaping `$_POST['myInput']` which invites for SQL injection attack.
3. `SSP::simple` doesn't accept parameter containing `WHERE` clause, you need to use `SSP::complex` instead.

Corrected code is shown below:

```
<?php
//...HERE I have defined these: $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns 

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

$conn = SSP::db($sql_details);

$where="office=".$conn->quote($_POST['myInput']);

echo json_encode(SSP::complex($_GET,$conn,$table,$primaryKey,$columns,$where));
```